# If a polynomial sends integers to integers, are their coefficients rational?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p$ be a polynomial so that $p(n)$ are integers for all $n\in \mathbb Z$. Is it possible that it has some irrational coefficients?

**Remark**: A similar question to ask is if all the coefficients are integers: this is not true ($p(x) = \frac{1}{2}x(x+1)$) is an counterexample).

Comment: "*Real polynomials that take on only integer values*"  By this do you mean that $f(\Bbb R)\subseteq \Bbb Z$?  Or do you mean that $f(\Bbb Z)\subseteq \Bbb Z$?  If it was the first, considering that polynomials are continuous functions if $f$ happened to take on more than one integer value then it must take on all real values between that as well and would therefore not take on only integer values.  The only such polynomials then are the constant polynomials, the only such of which that take on integer values have their sole coefficient being an integer and therefore not irrational.

Comment: A polynomial's coefficients are uniquely determined by $f(0), f(1), \cdots, f(n)$, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: No, all the coefficients will be rational. They are a solution of a system with rational coefficients and with a unique solution.

Comment: @orangeskid You then should probably add, that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, and solving such a system could be made through operations in the field

Comment: Consider the polynomial $\pi x  - \pi x$. The question should clarify that a simplified polynomial is intended to avoid this kind of triviality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comment: Let $n$ be the degree of the polynomial. Write

$$ p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots +a_n x^n.$$

Then by substituting $x=0, 1, \cdots, n$,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &\cdots &0 \\ 1 & 1^1 & \cdots & 1^n \\ \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots \\ 1 & n^1 & \cdots & n^n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} p(0) \\ p(1) \\ \vdots \\ p(n) \end{pmatrix}$$

The square matrix on the left is more or less the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), which is invertible. Thus $a_0, \cdots, a_n$ are all rational, since

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &\cdots &0 \\ 1 & 1^1 & \cdots & 1^n \\ \vdots & \vdots & &\vdots \\ 1 & n^1 & \cdots & n^n\end{pmatrix} ^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} p(0) \\ p(1) \\ \vdots \\ p(n) \end{pmatrix},$$

$p(i) \in \mathbb Z$ and the inverse matrix has rational coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I thought I'd put an answer I personally found a bit more elementary, and actually gives you an explicit way of writing out $p$. It still requires elementary linear algebra, though.

Let $p(t)$ be a polynomial in real coefficients (you can take complex coefficients if you prefer, just replace every instance of the word real with complex) that maps integers to integers, and let $d$ denote the degree of $p(t)$. Let $\mathbb{R}_d[t]$ denote the real vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq d$. The space $\mathbb{R}_d[t]$ has dimension $d + 1$, and in fact has a basis $\left\{ 1, t, t^2, \ldots, t^d \right\}$.
For $j = 0, 1, \ldots, d$, let $\phi_j : \mathbb{R}_d[t] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the linear functional
$$\phi_j(p) = p(j) ,$$
and let $\Phi : \mathbb{R}_d[t] \to \mathbb{R}^{d + 1}$ be the linear map
$$
\Phi(p) = \begin{bmatrix}
p(0) \\
p(1) \\
\vdots \\
p(d)
\end{bmatrix} .
$$
I claim that $\Phi$ is injective. If $p \in \ker \Phi$, i.e. $\Phi(p) = \mathbf{0}$, then $p(0) = p(1) = \cdots = p(d) = 0$, so $p(t)$ has factors $t, t - 1, \ldots, t - d$. Thus $p(t)$ is divisible by $t(t - 1) \cdots (t - d)$, i.e. there exists a polynomial $q(t)$ such that $p(t) = q(t) t (t - 1) \cdots (t - d)$. But if $q(t)$ is nonzero, then
$$\deg p = \deg q + \deg \left( t (t - 1) \cdots (t - d) \right) \geq d + 1 ,$$
since $t (t - 1) \cdots (t - d)$ has degree $d + 1$. But this means that $\deg p > d = \deg p$, an obvious impossibility. So it follows that $q$ is the zero polynomial, and thus that $p$ is.

Therefore $\Phi$ is an injective linear map. Since $\mathbb{R}_d[t]$ and $\mathbb{R}^{d + 1}$ are both of dimension $d + 1$, it follows that $\Phi$ is bijective. But we can actually write out the inverse. For each $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n$, set
$$q_k(t) = t (t - 1) \cdots (t - k + 1) (t - k - 1) (t - k - 2 ) \cdots (t - d) = \frac{t (t - 1) \cdots (t - d)}{t - k} .$$
Then
$$\phi_j (q_k) = \begin{cases}
\prod_{0 \leq \ell \leq d, \ell \neq k} \left(\ell - k \right) & \textrm{if $j = k$} \\ 0 & \textrm{if $j \neq k$}
\end{cases}$$
Set $$\tilde{q}_k(t) = \frac{q_k(t)}{\prod_{0 \leq \ell \leq d, \ell \neq k} \left(\ell - k \right)}$$
So
$$p(t) = \sum_{j = 0}^d \phi_j(p) \tilde{q}_j(t) .$$