# Polynomials giving integer outputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Given a polynomial $p(x)$ that outputs an integer for every integer input $x$, is it necessary for $p(x)$ to have rational coefficients?

Comment: The version with rational coefficients is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424765/if-a-polynomial-sends-integers-to-integers-are-their-coefficients-rational).

Answer (score 2):

No, say $$p(x) = {1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 2}x$$

or for every natural number $n$: $$p(x) ={x+n\choose n}$$

Comment: I meant to say rational coefficients. Does this change anything

Comment: @user562804: As the duplicate notice says, you should ask a *new* question, especially since you did not type what you meant the first time. Please be more careful when asking a question--we want this site to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers.